# How to set up multiple overlays/forms with jQuery Tools?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-tools

So, I am a **TOTAL** jQuery / jQuery Tools newbie, but I'm learning...  Here's my current issue:

Suppose I have a page that lists a number of users -- one div per user, with a name, picture, and the like.  Somewhere in these divs are links that you can click that will bring up a jQuery Tools overlay containing a form.  This form will let you edit the information about the user and save it back to the site.  No big deal.

The question my little newbie brain is struggling with is (of course) how to implement it.  My current understanding of all this is that, I need to create a separate div containing the form for each user, wired up in some way such that clicking the link for a specific user will present the overlay/form associated with that user.  This is as opposed to there being a single DIV on the page that contains the form, and that gets parameterized and re-used in some way for each of the users.

Is this the right philosophical approach?  The coding doesn't seem too hard; I'm just looking to confirm that I'm taking the right approach before I get started.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for jquery-tools shows you exactly how to do this:

http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/overlay/external.html

Comment: Indeed.  I was all over the overlay examples, but kinda blew past the "external" example since it didn't seem on point.  Things are on their way to working now; thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be:

1. Create a click handler for your link
2. When the user click the link open the overlay dialog and make an ajax call to the server to a method that returns the FORM markup
3. Replace the overlay content with the received markup on Ajax Success
4. Inside the form returned by the previous method there will be a submit button that simply submit the form
5. Close the overlay

Using this way you can have the form used as a template and a method that fill it up with data related to a certain user.